# .htaccess Redirect non-www to www and main domain to sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect my non www domain to www and to a subfolder

I was able to redirect the domain to the subfolder with this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subdir/ /subdir%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

now I want to redirect my domain to www. how do I do that?

if I try to add www infront of my doman it still shows a non-www domain

Comment: do you want redirect only main domain like this domain.com or every things like domain.com/whatever to domain.com/subdir/whatever? and you want to show new url or just internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
# rewrite /root to subfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subdir/ /subdir%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks @starkeen, but it doesn't work, also it adds the directory path to the URL..

Comment: Do you mean this redirects `example.com/file` to `www.example.com/subdir/file` changing the url in browser address bar?

Comment: I have a domain which points to public_html folder. I created a folder inside the public_html folder `domain.com`.. what I need to do it redirect domain.com to that subfolder without URL.. so URL remains `domain.com` but it shows the contents of the subfolder.. also I want the `domain.com` to become `www.domain.com`

Comment: @kimCarlo The code I posted does exactly what you want. Try clearing your browser cache and test the code again.